# PHP Laravel - using jQuery to access mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, laravel

I am encountering an issue.
My database is rather complex.

For the questions, following tables are used:

- product - containing the product details. e.g. shoe
- productattribute - containing the different variations of the product. e.g. black, size 12. Product key is in this table
- productsupplier - containing the specific supplier of the specific product attributes. e.g.black shoe, size 12 can be by multiple suppliers. So productattribute key is in product supplier.
- PO - purchase order. PO is supplier specific. Product supplier key comes in it.

Hope the DB relations are clear.

So I am making the Purchase Order form.
In step 1, the user will select the supplier. Shown in the picture

[image]

When they click next, all the products relating to that supplier will be shown. Shown in the picture

[image]

What I want to do next is when they click on any of the names, the data of productattribute table is showed. It carries the other attributes, like color, size etc. Here, jquery will be used and I am not of a jquery user so I am encountering trouble.

In the PHP backend, I have grouped the product names in an array. I did this because in the dropdown I showed the picture above of, I wanted each product's name to be displayed once only, not as many times as it has the attributes. So I grouped the products. Following is the code for the array and grouping:

```
public function new_po_next(Request $request)
    {
        $product = array();
        $supplier = \App\supplier::where('user_id', $request->supplier)->first();
        $productsupplier = \App\productsupplier::where('supplier_id', $supplier->id)->get();
        foreach ($productsupplier as $ps)
        {
            $productattribute = \App\productattribute::where('id', $ps->productattribute_id)->first();

                $prod = \App\product::where('id', $productattribute->product_id)->first();

                    $product [] = [
                        'prod_supp_id' => $ps->id,
                        'prod_supp_prodattid' => $ps->productattribute_id,
                        'prod_supp_cost' => $ps->cost,
                        'prod_att_id' => $productattribute->id,
                        'prod_att_color' => $productattribute->color_id,
                        'prod_att_size' => $productattribute->size_id,
                        'prod_att_material' => $productattribute->material_id,
                        'prod_att_prodid' => $productattribute->product_id,
                        'prod_id'=>$prod->id,
                        'prod_name' =>$prod->name,
                    ];
        }
        $productCollection = collect($product);
        $groupedProductCollection = $productCollection->groupBy('prod_name');

        $groupedProduct = $groupedProductCollection->all(); // all method will convert it back to array

       // var_dump($groupedProduct);die();
        $status = $request->status;
        $deldate = $request->deldate;
        $discount = $request->discount;
        return view("vendor.new-po-next")->with('status', $status)
            ->with('deldate', $deldate)->with('discount', $discount)->with('product', $product)->with('groupedProduct', $groupedProduct);
    }
```

Then in the blade, I am showing like as follows:

```
<select name="product_name" id="product_name">
                                                <option selected="true" disabled="disabled">Choose Product</option>.
                                                    @foreach(array_keys($groupedProduct) as $prod_name)
                                                        <option value="{{ $groupedProduct[$prod_name]}}"> {{$prod_name}} </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                            </select>
```

Now it's going to the javascript/jquery code as follows:

```
 $('select').on('change', function() {
               var prodName = $('#product_name').find(":selected").text();
```

And I haven't gone any further.
What I need to do next is access the productattribute tableusing the prodName in order to retrieve all the attributes/variations of the particular product and display a table through which user can select the variations that they need.

Can someone please help?
If there's anything that you don't understand, please let me know.
If you understand it, please let me know how should I proceed further.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have understood your problem, but you can solve it by making a request through ajax, which will return the product attributes according to the name.

```
 $('select').on('change', function() {
     var prodName = $('#product_name').find(":selected").text();
     var token =  $('#_token').val().
     $.ajax({
         url:'/ruta',
         data:{
            _method: 'get', 
            _token : token,
            'prodName': prodName
         },
         type:'get',
         success:  function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            //HERE WOULD GO THE LOGIC TO PLACE THE INFORMATION IN YOUR FORM from the response
         },
         error:function(x,xs,xt){
            console.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(x) +"\n error string: "+ xs + "\n error throwed: " + xt);
         }
      });
})
```

Then later you would create the get type path and in your controller you would create the function that receives that request and returns the data, recommended in * json * format.

```
return response()->json(['data' => $data]);
```

** Note: ** Keep in mind that if you are going to make the request through ajax, you have to create an input where the csrf token is saved like this.

```
<input type="hidden" id="_token" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

Comment: Hi there! I did what you said. Added the input type hidden field to add the token, the JSON response and ajax function. It's giving 

``` Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ajax' of undefined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous>  ``` . 

This error. If I remove ``` _token : token, ``` this, then I get 500 Internal Server Error. Can you please give a solution to this?